# What does "!S:~%I%,1!"=="" mean?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I found some sample code but I am unable to get what this `if` condition means:

```
set /p sourceDB=Enter Source DB: %=%    
set S=%sourceDB%
set I=0
set L=-1
:l ----- Forget about this line
if "!S:~%I%,1!"=="" goto ld
if "!S:~%I%,1!"=="/" set K=%I%
if "!S:~%I%,1!"=="@" set Z=%I%
if "!S:~%I%,1!"==":" set Y=%I%
set /a I+=1
goto l
```

Comment: Looks like a var within a var :) I'm assuming the DB stands for database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that this is how you get substrings in batch.

---

When you extract a substring, you use the format `%string_name:~index_of_first_character_in_substring,length_of_substring%` or, if the value of either `index_of_first_character_in_substring` or `length_of_substring` is contained in a separate variable (in your example, the index is its own variable), you can enable delayed expansion and use the format `!string_name:~%variable_whose_value_is_the_index_of_first_character_in_substring%,length_of_substring!`

In this case, your main string is in a variable called `%S%`, you are starting at character `%I%`, and grabbing `1` character.

The line you've told us to ignore is actually pretty important, as it's used to loop through the entire string.

The entire line `"!S:~%I%,1!"==""` is used to check if the substring is empty -- that is, the script is finished iterating through the string. There are also conditions for if the substring is `/`, `@`, and `:`; with K, Z, and Y respectively containing the indices of those substrings.